# Flask - Database Info and HTML - Can't find entries

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, sql

at the moment I'm sitting on a project where I need to get database informations to a html side. After challenging getting it running something won't work.

here are some code snippets:

Database:

```
 c.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rooms (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            code TEXT,
            alias TEXT,
            capacity INTEGER,
            manager TEXT,
            has_collab_device BOOLEAN,
            phone TEXT,
            network TEXT,
            floor_id INTEGER,
            FOREIGN KEY (floor_id) REFERENCES floors(id)
        )
    ''')

floors = [("1st",), ("2nd",), ("3rd",), ("4th",), ("5th",), ("6th",), ("7th",), ("8th",)]
    c.executemany('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO floors (floor_number) VALUES (?)', floors)

    rooms_1st = [
        ("A0F0002", "Berlin", 8, "AA@company.com", 0, "1001", "Internal", 1),
        ("A0F0004", "München", 8, "AC@company.com,", True, "1002", "Internal", 1),
        ("A0G0002", "Stuttgart", 8, "AE@company.com", True, "1003", "External", 1),
        ("A0G0004", "Frankfurt", 8, "AG@company.com", 0, "1004", "Internal", 1)
    ]

c.executemany('INSERT INTO rooms (code, alias, capacity, manager, has_collab_device, phone, network, floor_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', rooms)
```

So here is the Problem that when I'm using the JavaScript with:

```
const roomInfo = document.createElement('div');
                    roomInfo.classList.add("room-info");
                    roomInfo.textContent = `${room.code} - ${room.alias}`;
```

that ${room.code} stays at "undefined". In my Understanding is need to be "A0F0002". Where is my fault?

Also I added a Search Container:

```
        <div class="search-container">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo/room_search_logo.png') }}" alt="Search" class="search-logo">
            <input type="text" id="roomSearchInput" placeholder="Search for room ...">
        </div>
```

therefore the JavaScript is:

```
document.getElementById('roomSearchInput').addEventListener('input', function() {
    const searchTerm = this.value;
    if (searchTerm.length > 2) {
        fetch(`/search-rooms?query=${encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data); 
                
                const roomListContainer = document.getElementById('roomListContainer');
                roomListContainer.innerHTML = ''; 
                
                data.forEach(room => {
                    const roomDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    roomDiv.classList.add('room-entry');
                    roomDiv.textContent = `${room.code} - ${room.alias}`;
                    roomListContainer.appendChild(roomDiv);
                });
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching search results:', error));
    } else {
    }
});
```

But it won't even try to search a room and I don't know why.

Have you any idea?

AI support without solution.